# Start and End Date Validation

Tags: javascript, adminform, validation

I have been working on admin form where I want the user to select `Start Date` and `End Date`.

I have to provide validation such that the `End Date` must be greater than `Start Date`.

[image]

Could anyone pls help me in providing defautl Magento validation class for start and end date with the scenario as explained above?

If its not possible with default Magento validation, pls post custom JS code.

Also this is in my form for date range

```
        $dateFormatIso = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateFormat(
            Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT
        );

$fieldset->addField('start_date', 'date', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('myhelper')->__('Start Date'),
            'name'      => 'start_date',
            'note'      => $this->__('Start Date'),
            'required'  => true,
            'image'     => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
            'format'    => $dateFormatIso,
             'class'    => 'required-entry validate-date validate-date-range date-range-start_date-from'
        ));

        $fieldset->addField('end_date', 'date', array(
            'label'     => Mage::helper('myhelper')->__('End Date'),
            'name'      => 'end_date',
            'note'      => $this->__('End Date'),
            'required'  => true,
            'image'     => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
            'format'    => $dateFormatIso,
            'class'     => 'required-entry validate-date validate-date-range date-range-end_date-to'
        ));
```

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using Magento's validator's `validate-date-range` class on your fields.

If you add this to both fields then it will get the to date and compare the two values.

If get the to date value using the following code:

```
var m = /\bdate-range-(\w+)-(\w+)\b/.exec(elm.className);
if (!m || m[2] == 'to' || Validation.get('IsEmpty').test(v)) {
    return true;
}
```

So what you will need to do is add a class in the format `date-range-your_attribute_code-from` and `date-range-your_attribute_code-to`. Doing this will mean that Magento is able to link the two fields.

For an example of this check out the design tab on CMS pages. `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Cms/Page/Edit/Tab/Design.php`

The following is a more detailed explanation about the classes:

1. `validate-date`: this makes sure that the entered value is a valid date,
2. `validate-date-range`: this does the comparison between two dates when the have the correct classes,
3. `date-range-custom_data-from`, `date-range-custom_data-to`: these link the two dates so that they can be used in the date range check, **note that these should be the same apart from the `-to` and `-from`** means it can be **`date-range-xxxx-from`** and **`date-range-xxxx-to`** respectively.

Comment: Two questions:
1`) How does this work -> `'class'     => 'required-entry validate-date validate-date-range date-range-custom_theme-
to'`

2`) How to input `date-range-your_attribute_code-from` as I do not have my custom attribute code.

Comment: @Jordan how are you making the form if you do not have your attribute code? Technically it does not matter as long as the two have the same thing in `attribute_code` it is just to link the two fields.

Comment: I just used class mentioned in `app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Cms/Page/Edit/Tab/Design.php` and it worked. Do I need to change it ?

Comment: technically no, if it works for your attributes then it is fine, it really only using that class to link the two fields

Comment: Okay, so whats the clear difference between `validate-date`,  `validate-date-range` and `date-range-custom_theme-from`. Also which one to use precisely, if validating start and end date ?

Comment: @Jordan see update

Comment: I am using `date-range-start_date` instead of `date-range-custom_theme-from' and same for end_date, but its not working if I used my ID

Comment: @Jordan you need the `-from` and `-to` suffixes on your classes. Try `date-range-start_data-from` and `date-range-start_data-to`

Comment: I know am that close to achieve what you're saying, but still can not get it done. Pls see my question update.

Comment: Could you pls help by responding.

Comment: @Jordan the `date-range` should have the same attribute specified in the classes not start and end date, try `date-range-start_data-to` and `date-range-start_data-from`

Comment: Thanks a lot for clear explanation. What matters is a unique attrib code for -to and -from to check date range.

Answer (score 0):

All of the validation are tied to the Java Script validation rules defined under

> js/prototype/validation.js

File

You can customize you code there

Comment: Do you have the customized code that will work ?

Comment: I would highly discourage modifying the Magento core file `js/prototype/validation.js`. You can add custom validations in a separate JS file...